# ASP.NET Identity Login query customization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

Can I customize the query for Login while using asp.net identity for web api? Basically, I want to write my own query to authenticate and generate token.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own UserStore by implementing IUserStore (and whatever other interfaces you want your store to provide: IUserPasswordStore, IUserRoleStore, IUserEmailStore, IUSerLockoutStore etc), and write your own TokenProvider by implementing IUserTokenProvider.